# Error transitioning using jQuery addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I have a simple `input[type="text"]` and I want to transition its width when clicking on it.

I mean I want to slide it on the left like this: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rexhin/gUS6s/2/)

I don't know why this isn't working.

Here is my fiddle: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rexhin/gUS6s/5/)

```
<input type="text" id="menu" />
```

This is my css.

```
#menu {
    width:32px;
    position:absolute;
    right:50%;
    transition: width .8s;
}

.slide {
    width:180px;
}
```

This is my JS.

```
$("#menu").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("slide");
});
```

Comment: It might also be useful for you to use -webkit-transition as well. Doesn't fix your problem, but allows Android < 4.4 to get the animation too. Reference: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You dont have to use jQuery for this.

You can use [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) selector.

Just add this to your CSS

```
#menu:focus {
    width:180px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gUS6s/9/)

Comment: Thank you, I like this pure CSS solution.

Comment: Can I do this using position relative 'cause I don't want to break my layout?

Comment: @rexhin Yes you can do it. Positioning is not affecting the :focus selector

Comment: Yes but the problem is that it slides to the right not to the left.
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rexhin/gUS6s/32/
@laaposto

Answer (score 4):

The problem is [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), where the id-rule has precedence over the class-rule. You can create a rule with higher precedence by combining both the id and the class values.

```
#menu.slide {
    width:180px;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7jgKU/)

Answer (score 4):

It's because of CSS specificity, change it to

```
#menu {
    width:32px;
    position:absolute;
    right:50%;
    transition: width .8s;
}

#menu.slide {
    width:180px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gUS6s/7/)

Styles set on an ID override the styles on the class, as ID's are more specific.

Answer (score 2):

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/gUS6s/12/)

A CSS ID selector is more specific than a class selector, unless you include `!important` in the rule.

```
.slide {
    width:180px !important;
}
```

`!important` will override all other CSS rules. As noted in the comments, if you have a more organic way of increasing the specificity of the rule, such as using the ID `#menu.slide`, that is typically preferred to using `!important`, since this can create undesired clashes with other stylesheets. However, that particular example will only work if you're only using this solution for a single text-box.

Also, you need to wrap jQuery code that relies on DOM elements in a DOM-ready handler:

```
$(function () {
    $("#menu").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("slide");
    });
});
```

Comment: @Sudharsan - don't be daft. !important is a tool like any other. Of course you can use it. You just shouldn't abuse it.

Comment: Some of its drawbacks include:
    Encourages sloppy, poorly thought-out code
    Creates code that is less maintainable
    Overrides styles declared in user style sheets, thus degrading accessibility

Comment: @Sudharsan And some of the drawbacks of `#menu.slide` are that it won't work if the OP requires this solution to be extensible for use with other elements. Without full knowledge of the markup either option may not be a perfect solution, but this is a valid option given current information. I will update the answer to note your concerns however.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.